# While loops does not show all results php, it eliminates one result

Tags: php, while-loop

Every time i use this code it eliminates one result.

Lets say if i have 10 rows from the database, it will only display 9 rows

**I am aware this code is not in PDO or MySQLI, but that isn,t the issue**

```
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_tutorunit = "SELECT * FROM tutorunit WHERE tutorID = $colname_unitg";
$tutorunit = mysql_query($query_tutorunit, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_tutorunit = mysql_fetch_assoc($tutorunit);
$totalRows_tutorunit = mysql_num_rows($tutorunit);


$confirmtwo = "";
while ($row_tutorunit = mysql_fetch_array($tutorunit)) {
    $confirmtwo .= $row_tutorunit["code"];
}
echo $confirmtwo;
```

When i use do while it shows all the results.

```
<?php do { ?>
<p><?php echo $row_tutorunit["code"]; ?></p>
<?php } while ($row_tutorunit = mysql_fetch_assoc($tutorunit)); ?>
```

But i do not want to use do-while 
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Which row is missing? First? Last? One from somewhere in the middle?

Comment: Please show us your code around it. I can probably bet that you already have a line with `mysql_fetch_array($tutorunit)` above this code.

Comment: I would guess you are doing a `mysql_fetch_array($tutorunit)` before you start the while loop

Comment: If you do not use numeric indexes, I advice to change `mysq_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: BUt when i use do-while it shows all the results. but i dont want to use the do while. this has always happened to me

Comment: @barell even with that. it still eliminates one value

Comment: *Called it!*, if the do-while works, this means somewhere above this code you already called `mysql_fetch_array($tutorunit)` otherwise the variable wouldn't be defined and you wouldn't see all correct results

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @Rizier123 thank you i have seen it defined somewhere at the top an i have silenced it and it worked

Comment: @Rizier123 I am aware of the mysql_* function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that line:

```
$row_tutorunit = mysql_fetch_assoc($tutorunit);
```

Both `mysql_fetch_assoc` and `mysql_fetch_array` move the pointer.